# Javascript modularity

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, modularity

I am studying the possibility of building Javascript applications in the Java / OSGi modularity style. I am sure I will not manage to actually reach the kind of flexibility that OSGi provides, but I would need to get to at least the following list:

- split javascript code as modules, each module would lay in its own git repository
- ideally, as little as possible dependencies between modules and definitely no circular dependencies between modules
- have 2 or more "main" javascript applications that will use the modules described above

If I will manage to setup the above then I will probably want to be able to organize modules as layers like: core layer with several modules, ui layer, applications layer.

Are there any javascript libraries that help building the above setup? Is something like this possible in javascript?

Note: When I say javascript, I don't actually mean plain javascript. I am going to use a library like ExtJS or jQuery for the UI part at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) an implementation of Asynchronous Module Definition

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was answered javascript now has native implementaitons of classes and modules that can give you what you need without having to use a 3rd party library.

js modules alow you to have a module or code and import methods (or everything) from it (a bit like in python and ruby)

```
// utilities.js
function something () {
 // some great code 
}

export function util() {
  something();
}

//import a method
import {util} from "utilities.js";

// or import everything
import "utilities.js";
```

you can find more on [es6 modules here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

js classes are syntax suger over prototypal structure in js and can be used the same way as in more trandtional OOP languages

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    // constructor code
  }

  add() {
    // some method
  }
}

var myObject = new MyClass();
```

You can find out more about [es6 classes here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)